# How to handle db concurrency?

Tags: database, concurrency, cassandra

Let's say I've got 3 tables (`LiveDataTable`, `ReducedDataTable`, `ScheduleTable`).

Basically I've got a stream of events -> whenever I receive an event I write extracted data of this event to `LiveDataTable`.

The problem is that there's a huge number of events that's why `LiveDataTable` may become really huge, so I've got another `ReducedDataTable` where I combine rows from `LiveDataTable` (think of selecting 100 rows from `LiveDataTable`, reducing it to 1 row and write it to `ReducedDataTable` and then deleting these 100 rows from `LiveDataTable`).

In order to determine the right time of performing these `reducing operations` there's `ScheduleTable`. You may think that 1 row `ScheduleTable` corresponds to `1 reducing operation`.

I want to be able to support `List<Data> getData()` method from `Interface`. There're 2 cases: I should either read from `ReducedDataTable` only or merge the results from `ReducedDataTable` and `LiveDataTable`.

Here's how my caching works step-by-step:

1. Read 1 row from `ScheduleTable`
2. Read from `LiveDataTable`
3. Write to `ReducedDataTable` (at least 4 rows)
4. Remove (<= INT_MAX) rows from `LiveDataTable`
5. Remove 1 row from  `ScheduleTable`

The problem is I want to determine whether I should read from `LiveDataTable` and `ReducedDataTable` programmatically when receiving `getData()` request. For every step (before #3) I want to read from `LiveDataTable` and then I'd like to read from `ReducedDataTable`. How do I determine what step I'm currently at when receiving `getData()` request?

The reason I asked this questions I believe this's a common problem in DB when handling concurrency.

Comment: This does all sound rather convoluted. If your writes are immutable and you structure your data model correctly then you should be able to write into the one table and then the entries update older ones. Perhaps though there is a reason why you cannot do this?

Comment: I use Cassandra so it doesn't follow ACID.

Comment: I should have been a bit clearer sorry. Even with Cassandra this seems convoluted. One of the recommended approaches with Cassandra is to have a immutable data model as you cannot guarantee when a given write might make it into the cluster as this is determined by a number of factors. Of course you can use things like LWTs but this is expensive and will lose you some performance due to the paxos approach. For example your combining rows from one table into another, effectively doing a ETL each time. Can you not key your partition with a timestamp too or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming that your compaction process is fast enough)
You can first optimistically read from the small table and if the data is missing - then read from the non-compacted one.
In most cases there will be only one request, not two.

Otherwise you can maintain the timestamp of the data that has been already compacted.